# Why do we need a character pointer when working with read and write functions c++?

Tags: c++

So i have been watching some youtube tutorial on how work with binary files and structure arrays in c++ and all of them seem to put a character pointer on the arguments of the read() and write() functions, but non of them explained why.

Since a binary file contains only zeros and ones shouldn't we only tell it the size bits we are going to write?

Forgive me if this question sound dumb.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Post code as properly formatted text.

Comment: *So i have been watching some youtube tutorial on how work with binary files and structure arrays* -- Is this where most of the erroneous "binary file reading/writing" questions come from, by watching this YT video?  I'm trying to guess where it comes from, since there are thousands of questions posted here that contain attempts of "binary file reading/writing" on types that cannot work this way.  Hopefully whoever put out this video explains that this cannot be used by non-POD structs/classes and struct/classes with pointer members.

Comment: *"Since a binary file contains only zeros and ones shouldn't we only tell it the size bits we are going to write?"* -- you mean, for example, tell `write()` that you want to write 80 bits, but don't tell it which bits to write? (That's how I would interpret "only tell".) *Did you have an alternative in mind, some other way to specify the data to write?*

Comment: Yes, don't use YT to learn C++ if you are a beginner.  If you are an intermediate or advanced C++ programmer and you want to pin down certain techniques or some more advanced, focused material, there is nothing wrong with the appropriate YT video, like the ones put out by C++ conferences.  But in general, don't use YT to learn C++.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest addressable piece of data is a **byte**, which on almost any system you're likely to come across is 8 bits.

The `char` datatype accesses a single byte, so that's what is normally used to read and write raw to and from a file.